# Animation freezes when processing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, animation

I have a custom animation wich i am calling with this method:

```
- (void)spinWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options directionForward:(BOOL)directionForward {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:options
                 animations:^{

                     CATransform3D transform;

                     if (!directionForward) {

                         transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

                     } else {

                         transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                         transform.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0;
                         transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI - 0.0001f /*full rotation*/, 0, 1, 0.0f);

                     }

                     self.logoImageView.layer.transform = transform;

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     if (!_animating && options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {

                         [self spinWithOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut directionForward:NO];

                     } else if (options == UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear) {

                         [self spinWithOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear directionForward:!directionForward];

                     } else {

                         // animation finished

                     }

                 }];
```

}

but I have a problem, when the animation runs and I do some processing from a server with `AFNetworking` and `CoreData` the animation freezes, i think the main thread is blocked but I also have a `MBProgresHUD` and that doesn't freeze. Any idea how i can make this animation not freeze?

Comment: Put your code related to AFNetworking and CoreData in background thread.

Comment: @Mrunal is right you need to put some more code regarding AFNetworking

Comment: I don't think the code is the problem, MBPRogresHUD works ... and putting all the AFNetworking code and CoreData on a background thread is not an an option, it's to much work to do...

Comment: @guNNer2bad sorry pal but thats it -- you need to free the UI thread

Comment: the hud is offloading some animation / drawing code -- not a good call IMO - ui manipulation should stay on main thread

Comment: provide a working (or rather not working) example that shows your issue: http://www.sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

you do the animation and all the networking on the same thread. only one thing can run on one thread at a time though so your loading blocks the animation.

**you need to offload tasks so the thread can run just one thing. ANY ui modification needs to happen on the main thread, so we offload the networking.**

```
- startMyLongMethod {
    [self startAnimation]; //your spin thingy

    //get a background thread from GCD and do the work there
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        //do longRunning op (afnetwork and json parsing!)
        id result = [self doWork];

        //go back to the main thread and stop the animation
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateUI:result];
            [self stopAnimation];//your spin thingy
        });
    });
```

}

note: example code and written inline! The approach should be clear now though

Comment: tried this method but same result, the animation stops before processing is finished, I call more methods async, and stop the spin on callback response but i have the same freeze issue.

Comment: it freezes or it stops too early? maybe the spin method is broken.. I don't get how your code should run for a given amount either

Comment: provide a working (or rather not working) example that shows your issue: http://www.sscce.org